# jQuery - show paragraph if textbox and dropdown are both empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a paragraph when both the textbox and dropdown are empty. I have them working separately but don't know how to combine them.

So basically, I want the dropdown and textbox and just one paragraph which will be shown when both the other fields are empty.

What I got so far:

```
<label>Place of birth</label>
<select id="placeOfBirth">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="01">City 1</option>
    <option value="02">City 2</option>
    <option value="03">City 3</option>
</select>
<p class="show_dd"> show this if dropdown is not selected </p> <br><br>

<label>Other</label>
<input id="other"><br>
<p class="show_text"> show this if field is empty </p> <br><br>


$('#placeOfBirth').change(function() {
    if($("#placeOfBirth").val()===""){ 
       $('.show_dd').show();
    } else {
       $('.show_dd').hide();
    }
});

$('#other').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#other').val().length == 0) {
        $('.show_text').show();
        $('#test').val($('#other').val());
    } else {
       $('.show_text').hide();
    }
 }).keyup();
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xseriff/uez59tgm/)

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/L6xw6jyn/#&togetherjs=QtnoRgCKH9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle so that both select and textbox hide and show the paragraph based on if they're populated with values.

```js
$('#placeOfBirth').change(hideParagraph);
$('#other').keyup(hideParagraph).keyup(); 

function hideParagraph() {
  if ($('#other').val().length == 0 && $("#placeOfBirth").val() === "") {
    $('.show_text').show();
  } else {
    $('.show_text').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Place of birth</label>
<select id="placeOfBirth">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="01">City 1</option>
    <option value="02">City 2</option>
    <option value="03">City 3</option>
</select>

<label>Other</label>
<input id="other"><br>
<p class="show_text"> Show this if one field is populated </p> <br><br>
```